# delete_all under find scope with joins in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I have a book model , a tag model and a join model called bookstags, they looks like following.

When I want to read all via_tags, Book.first.via_tags it works will,
but when I try to delete all related via_tags, I tried Book.first.via_tags.delete_all()
And I got an Exception.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "INNER": syntax error: DELETE FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "books_tags" ON "tags".id = "books_tags".tag_id WHERE (("books_tags".book_id = 25)) AND ("tags"."kind" = 0)
```

So I want to ask is, is it possible to perform delete_all with joins?

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :through =>  :books_tags
end

class BooksTags < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :tag
  def self.with_via_tag
    find(:all, :joins => :tag, :conditions => {:tags => {:kind => Tag.kind_index(:via)}})
  end
end

class Tags
  has_many :books_tags
  has_many :books, :through => :books_tags
  @kinds = [:via,:cate,:attr]
  def self.kind_index kind
    @kinds.index(kind)
  end
end
```

Comment: Any reason you are using `delete_all` rather than `destroy_all`?

Comment: I'm using it right now, there's really no reason, should I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because `delete_all` discards join information. See this answer for an alternate way of writing your query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639857/156109